# Merge multiple arrays in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking at an efficient way to merge multiple array props in an object.

The object, can have multiple array properties in there :

```
{
  "col0Codes": [
    "ABC",
    "XYZ",
    "UYA",
    "ZZA",
    "AAW",
    "MYP"
  ],
  "col1Codes": [
    "CNA",
    "ZYA",
    "OIA",
    "POQ",
    "LMO",
    "OPI"
  ],
  "col2Codes": [
    "CNA",
    "ZYA",
    "OIA",
    "POQ",
    "LMO",
    "OPI"
  ],
  "col3Codes": [
    "..."
  ],
  "col4Codes": [
    "..."
  ],
  ...
}
```

Result: All the codes in a single array

```
["ABC","XYZ","UYA","ZZA","AAW","MYP","CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI",....]
```

I've tried using `concat` but this creates a new array every single time and overwrites the previous one, I feel this is not fast and memory efficient.

```
let colCodes = []
 for (let i in data) {
 colCodes = colCodes .concat(i)
}
console.log(activityCodes)
```

I've tried using `push`, but for some reason it does not merge all the entries into one single array but creates a single array with number of props in the object as shown below

```
let colCodes = []
  for (let i in data) {
  colCodes.push(i)
}
console.log(colCodes)
[Array(6), Array(5), ....]
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this using `reduce`, if that is what'll be fast and mem efficient ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get an array of arrays using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and then flatten them to a single array using [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const data = {"col0Codes":["ABC","XYZ","UYA","ZZA","AAW","MYP"],"col1Codes":["CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI"],"col2Codes":["CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI"]};

const result = Object.values(data).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Old answer:

You can get the [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), then merge by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const data = {"col0Codes":["ABC","XYZ","UYA","ZZA","AAW","MYP"],"col1Codes":["CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI"],"col2Codes":["CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI"]};

const result = [].concat(...Object.values(data));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) with ES6 spread:

```js
const input={"col0Codes":["ABC","XYZ","UYA","ZZA","AAW","MYP"],"col1Codes":["CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI"],"col2Codes":["CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI"]};

console.log(Object.values(input).reduce((r,c) => [...r, ...c]))
```

Comment: Up voted. Thanks for the answer, just trying to get my head around what is happening with the syntax, will have to delve in a little further to understand how your code is flattening the object.

Comment: @SubSul In the reduce callback `(r,c) => [...r, ...c])`, the `r` represents the accumulator, `c` is the array element currently being iterated on. Then return value of this callback (`[...r, ...c]`) simply means that the contents of this array includes the elements of `r` and the elements of `c`.

Comment: @SubSul or you can simply do: `Object.values(input).reduce((r,c) => r.concat(c), [])`

Comment: @achacttn  and robe007 -> Thanks for the explanation guys.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use `Array.prototype.flat`, and call it on the values of the object:

```js
const input={"col0Codes":["ABC","XYZ","UYA","ZZA","AAW","MYP"],"col1Codes":["CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI"],"col2Codes":["CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI"]};

console.log(
  Object.values(input).flat()
);
```

Comment: **Caveat:** `.flat` is a new feature. If snippet throws error, its likely, you do not  have latest browsers.

Comment: Up voted. Thanks for the answer, but i'll require this working on IE as well. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```js
let obj = {"col0Codes": ["ABC","XYZ","UYA","ZZA","AAW","MYP"],
  "col1Codes": ["CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI"],
  "col2Codes": ["CNA","ZYA","OIA","POQ","LMO","OPI"],
  "col3Codes": ["..."],
  "col4Codes": ["..."]
}

let op = [];

for(let key in obj){
  op.push(...obj[key])
}

console.log(op)
```